# Webdriver.quit() ,not working properly when called in @AfterSuite annotation

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, testng

I have a two "test" in testng XML file, all are running parallel what my issue is that I called a `Webdriver.quit()` method in the `@AfterSuite` annotation, but it is only closing the last created browser instance not all opened browsers.

when I call in the `@AfterTest` annotation it gets closed.

below is my Testng file:

[image]

I created the driver in the base class and extend it in test classes.

code for creating driver instance.

```
@BeforeClass
@Parameters({"deviceName","platformName","platformVersion","udid","browserName","browserVersion","nodeIP","nodePort"})
public void startBrowser(String deviceName, String platformName, String platformVersion, String udid, String browserName, String browserVersion, String nodeIP, String nodePort)
       
    {
        DesiredCapabilities capabilities =DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "chromeDriverPath");
        ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
        capabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.ACCEPT_SSL_CERTS, true);
        driver = new ChromeDriver(capabilities);
    }
```

Comment: Created the driver in the base class and extend to the test classes

Answer (score 0):

AfterSuite is called once per suite.  What you have shown above is one suite executing two tests in parallel.  You need to make sure your driver is thread safe.

AfterTest gets called after `<test>` tag is over - so your webdriver if specific to a thread will get closed.

If you want to close all webdriver in aftersuite, you need to build a list of webdrivers and close each one individually.

Answer (score 0):

Because you have 2 `<test>`, TestNG is creating 2 instances (with the same after suite method). 
But testng consideres a suite method as single in the suite and will only call it once (the first it finds). 
That's why it is working with after test method which looks to be the one you should use.

BTW, as you want to close the driver in an after suite method, I suppose you create it in a before suite method which is not supposed to work for the same reasons. Could you detail where/how you create the driver ?